# How to efficiently lambdify a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, sympy, lambdify

I am using sympy to build a sparse (N^2 x N^2) matrix and trying to convert it to a sparse scipy matrix. It is used in a finite difference method to solved Schrödinger equation on 2D grid depending on a k-vector k = (kx, ky).

### Dense Matrix to SciPy

My current approach is to use lambdify to create function B from a sympy matrix A, that delivers a finite difference matrix for a certain k-vector, which I convert to the sparse matrix M.

```
N = 80
kx, ky = sp.symbols('kx ky')

A = dill.load(open("./A_{0}".format(N), "rb"))

B = sp.lambdify([kx, ky], A)

M = sparse.csc_matrix(B(1,0))

dill.dump(B, open("./B_{0}".format(N), "wb"))
```

My problem here is, that once N >= 80, I get a memory overflow error (exceeding 32 GB) for lambdify and the lambdify process is killed.

### Lambdify a Sparse Sympy Matrix

Alternatively, I thought of providing lambdify directly with a sparse matrix, but I am unaware which type of sparse matrix sympy is creating ...

```
B = sp.lambdify([kx, ky], sp.SparseMatrix(A))
M = B(1,0)
```

... and trying to evaluate B in the line `M = B(1,0)` leads to an error

```
File "<lambdifygenerated-1>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'shape'
```

I am using Python 3.7.6, sympy 1.6 and scipy 1.4.1

Comment: Where's the traceback?  Where's a small reproducible example?  None of us likes to import a mega-file that could end up producing a memory error.

Answer (score 1):

While I've worked a lot with `scipy.sparse` I haven't used `sy.SparseMatrix` before.  Looking at the docs, I can make a simple one (in an `isympy` session):

```
In [4]: A = SparseMatrix(4,4, {(1,1): x, (3,3):y})                              

In [5]: A                                                                       
Out[5]: 
⎡0  0  0  0⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  x  0  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  0  0  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎣0  0  0  y⎦

In [6]: B=lambdify([x,y], A)                                                    

In [7]: B                                                                       
Out[7]: <function _lambdifygenerated(x, y)>

In [10]: M=B(10,20)                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-442f4a9e4340> in <module>
----> 1 M=B(10,20)

<lambdifygenerated-1> in _lambdifygenerated(x, y)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
----> 2     return (coo_matrix([x, y], ([1, 3], [1, 3]), shape=(4, 4)))

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'shape'
```

So I got your error message.  And also got a clear indication of what kind of sparse matrix it was trying to create.  Didn't you see that?  I'm tempted to just stop at this point, since you clearly are with holding valuable information!!

===

The `B.__doc__` is:

```
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x, y)

Expression:

Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, x, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, y]])

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
    return (coo_matrix([x, y], ([1, 3], [1, 3]), shape=(4, 4)))
```

That's what the traceback showed.  Clearly it is trying to make a `sparse.coo_matrix`.  But there's an error, a missing layer of `()`. The correct way to setup the matrix is:

```
In [11]: from scipy import sparse                                               
In [14]: sparse.coo_matrix(([x,y],([1,3], [1,3])), shape=(4,4))                 
Out[14]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.object_'>'
    with 2 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [15]: print(_)                                                               
  (1, 1)    x
  (3, 3)    y
```

I can't do much with the `B` with symbolic `x` and `y` (not even display it as dense).

But if I put it in a function, I can provide value numeric values for the `x` and `y`.

```
In [16]: def foo(x,y): 
    ...:     return sparse.coo_matrix(([x,y],([1,3], [1,3])), shape=(4,4)) 
    ...:                                                                        

In [17]: foo(10,20).A                                                           
Out[17]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 20]])
```

So the `SparseMatrix` lambdify is wrong.  I won't try to suggest a fix.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and sorry if you had the impression I were "withholding information", this was out of neglect rather than intention.

Comment: To fix this, I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19632) and [pull request](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/19633) on Github